# Merge TFS changeset between branches rather than selecting files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am making changes in a feature branch and merging these across to the main development branch, by just merging the folders with modified files and letting TFS detect the files that need to be merged.

But is there not a way to say "just merge this changeset" so I know only the specific changes in a commit are being merged?

I am not having luck looking through the GUI or on Google for an answer one way or the other.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/01/19/what-is-a-cherry-pick-merge-and-why-do-you-recommend-against-them.aspx any help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is there something from the "Selected Changesets" merge option that isn't working for you?  You're able to select specific change sets to merge, though there can be [potential issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/01/19/what-is-a-cherry-pick-merge-and-why-do-you-recommend-against-them.aspx).

From the merge dialogue, select your source and target.  Make sure to select "Selected Changesets"

[image]

Now select the changeset your want to merge:

[image]

Finish the merge:

[image]

As per usual TFS merge, the changes are merged into your workspace, and not commited until you actually check in.

Comment: Thanks, this is it. I just seem to use the source control panel in VS mostly, and skip the 'proper' dialogs. It's pretty darn obvious, I just couldn't see it!

Comment: This will merge just the changes made in the specific folder you clicked on, if the changeset includes multiple folders at the same level, then what do?.